# Freeze the Scilab 6.0.1 console when iterating

Tags: command-line, scilab

When executing a for cycle in Scilab inside the console it locks up and does not transmit the information impression fluently.

[image]

For example

```
for i=1:280000, disp(i), end
```

But when running the previous loop in Scilab Advanced CLI shows fluently
the run of numbers

Comment: How did you installed Scilab? What is your Ubuntu version?